# Batch file: <part of command line> was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

Trying to execute a command inside a batch file and drop the result into a variable.

Here's what I would execute interactively:

```
curl -d "username=someUser" http://someServer/trusted
```

The result is a 15-20 character alpha-numeric string.

Here's my attempt at doing same in a batch file:

```
FOR /f %AA IN('curl -d \"username=someUser\" http://someServer/trusted') DO ECHO %AA
```

Error returned is:

```
//someServer/Trusted') was unexpected at this time
```

I thought I was dealing with some sort of escaping issue, so I added the \ symbols in front of my quotes. From what I've read, the : symobol in http doesn't need to be escaped, but it's interesting to me that's where the failure appears to "start".

Any ideas on this? I'm on Win8.1, FYI

Comment: 1. `for`-variables have one-char-variables  (%A instead of %AA)
2. you missed a space between `IN` and `(` 3. in a batch-file you have to double the percent-signs for the `for`-variable (%%A instead of %A)

Comment: That was it - I needed "IN (...." vs "IN(...) and then I needed to shorten the variable name to %%A. Please answer so I can mark your response as solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. for-variables have one-char-variables (%A instead of %AA)
2. you missed a space between IN and (
3. in a batch-file you have to double the percent-signs for the for-variable (%%A instead of %A)

Comment: This, I spent 20 minutes trying to figure out why my variable was wrong. I was using a word instead of a character T.T

Comment: I didn't understand on first read what "one-char-variables" meant. It means the name of the variable in the for loop must be one character long, like `%j`. Obvious but so weird I wanted to emphasize it.

Comment: So what is the correct command? I took this advice but still couldn't figure it out. `FOR /f %%A IN ('hello') DO echo %%A`

Comment: @serg06: `'` tells `for` that the string between is a command. Is `hello` a command? `for /f %%A in ("hello") do echo %%A` for strings, `for /f %%A in ('echo hello') do echo %%A` for commands.

Comment: @Stephan Thank you. My second mistake was attempting to do this in the terminal, but I guess you need to save it as a batch file first? That's unfortunate.

Comment: @serg06: if you want to use it directly on the command line, replace each `%%A` with just `%A`

Answer (score 0):

echo handles only one line, blanks brake it, you would need to pipe it maybe?